# Pandas - Data Cleaning - Add New Column with if else statement for text values

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements, rename

I have a list of publisher that looks like this :

```
+--------------+
|  Site Name   |
+--------------+
| Radium One   |
| Euronews     |
| EUROSPORT    |
| WIRED        |
| RadiumOne    |
| Eurosport FR |
| Wired US     |
| Eurosport    |
| EuroNews     |
| Wired        |
+--------------+
```

I'd like to create the following result:

```
+--------------+----------------+
|  Site Name   | Publisher Name |
+--------------+----------------+
| Radium One   | RadiumOne      |
| Euronews     | Euronews       |
| EUROSPORT    | Eurosport      |
| WIRED        | Wired          |
| RadiumOne    | RadiumOne      |
| Eurosport FR | Eurosport      |
| Wired US     | Wired          |
| Eurosport    | Eurosport      |
| EuroNews     | Euronews       |
| Wired        | Wired          |
+--------------+----------------+
```

I would like to understand how I can replicate this code I use in Power Query :

### search first 4 characters

if Text.Start([Site Name],4) = "WIRE" then "Wired" else

### search last 3 characters

if Text.End([Site Name],3) = "One" then "RadiumOne" else

If no match is found, then add "Rest"

It does not have to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with conditions created with [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
s = df['Site Name'].str.lower()
df['new'] = np.where(s.str[:4] == 'wire', 'Wired', 
            np.where(s.str[-3:] == 'one', 'RadiumOne', 'Rest'))
```

but if need your output, need also [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`title`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.title.html):

```
df['new1'] = np.where(s.str[:4] == 'wire', 'Wired', 
             np.where(s.str[-3:] == 'one', 'RadiumOne', s.str.split().str[0].str.title()))

print (df)
      Site Name        new       new1
0    Radium One  RadiumOne  RadiumOne
1      Euronews       Rest   Euronews
2     EUROSPORT       Rest  Eurosport
3         WIRED      Wired      Wired
4     RadiumOne  RadiumOne  RadiumOne
5  Eurosport FR       Rest  Eurosport
6      Wired US      Wired      Wired
7     Eurosport       Rest  Eurosport
8      EuroNews       Rest   Euronews
9         Wired      Wired      Wired
```

Comment: this is amazing. So if I understood correctly, the split and title will use the original site name if the result is Rest?

One last thing, is there a way to merge the new column, e.g. 'new', to an existing dataframe that contains site name, but simultaniously delete the old site name column?

The steps would be then a vlookup, which after matching, deletes/substitutes the old column automatically

Comment: no, there is different. I use split for two words name like `Eurosport FR` for `split` by whitespace - get `eurosport` and `fr` and then select first (`eurosport`) by `str[0]`. `title` is for add first letter to uppercase - so `eurosport` is changed to `Eurosport`.

Comment: also I get output if `Rest` to column `new` and if use spliting with title output is in `new1`. But if need overwrite old column `Site Name` by new values use assign - `df['Site Name'] = np.where(s.str[:4] == 'wire', 'Wired', 
             np.where(s.str[-3:] == 'one', 'RadiumOne', s.str.split().str[0].str.title()))
`

Comment: I thinkt the best is try it for all column - so you can use your sample - `df = pd.DataFrame({'Site Name': {0: 'Radium One', 1: 'Euronews', 2: 'EUROSPORT', 3: 'WIRED', 4: 'RadiumOne', 5: 'Eurosport FR', 6: 'Wired US', 7: 'Eurosport', 8: 'EuroNews', 9: 'Wired'}})
print (df)`

Comment: then test all my code per partes `print (df['Site Name'].str.lower())` for convert to lowercase, `print (df['Site Name'].str.lower().str.split())` for split by whitespace (default separator), `print (df['Site Name'].str.lower().str.split().str[0])` - select first value of list, `print (df['Site Name'].str.lower().str.split().str[0].str.title())` - convert first letter to uppercase

Comment: @MatteoM - some problem? `np.where` is much faster as `apply` - check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41166348/2901002)

Comment: @jezreal, sorry I changed by mistake!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `apply` method and function like :

```
def handle_text(txt):
    if txt.lower()[:4] == 'wire':
        return 'Wired'
    elif txt.lower()[-3:] == 'one':
        return 'RadiumOne'
    return 'Rest'

df['Publisher Name'] = df['Site Name'].apply(handle_text)
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you for the quick reply, is there a way, when I do a merge using your measure, to make sure that elif txt is blank then show Rest

Comment: `handle_text` is usual Python function, which accepts single string, do something and returns string. Of course you can do everything inside it.