# Why is np.where faster than pd.apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Sample code is here

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer' : ['Bob', 'Ken', 'Steve', 'Joe'],
                   'Spending' : [130,22,313,46]})

#[400000 rows x 4 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [129]: %timeit df['Grade']= np.where(df['Spending'] > 100 ,'A','B')
10 loops, best of 3: 21.6 ms per loop

In [130]: %timeit df['grade'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'A' if row['Spending'] > 100 else 'B', axis = 1)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.08 s per loop
```

Question taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41166160/3027854

Comment: One is vectorized, the other is a loop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think `np.where` is faster because use `numpy` array vectorized way and pandas is built on this arrays.

`df.apply` is slow, because it use `loops`.

`vectorize` operations are the fastest, then `cython routines` and then `apply`.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002) with better explanation of developer of pandas - Jeff.

Answer (score 1):

**Just adding a visualization approach to what have been said.**

Profile and total cumulative time of `df.apply` :
[image: df.apply profile]

We can see that the cimulative time is `13.8s`.

Profile and total cumulative time of `np.where` :
[image: np.where profile]

Here, the cumulative time is `5.44ms` which is `2500` times faster than `df.apply`

The figure above were obtained using the library `snakeviz`.
[Here](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/#generating-profiles) is a link to the library.

> > SnakeViz displays profiles as a sunburst in which functions are represented as arcs. A root function is a circle at the middle, with functions it calls around, then the functions those functions call, and so on. The amount of time spent inside a function is represented by the angular width of the arc. An arc that wraps most of the way around the circle represents a function that is taking up most of the time of its calling function, while a skinny arc represents a function that is using hardly any time at all.