# np.nan if contains character python

Tags: python

df1

```
Pet                            
Dog-Ralph                     
Cat                                  
2016-11-03 00:00:00
```

I have the dataframe above and I want to turn the '2016-11-03 00:00:00' value into a NaN value.  Since it is the only value that contains a colon, how do I turn that value into NaN like below:

```
Pet                            
Dog-Ralph                     
Cat                                  
NaN
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: It should be converted to `NaN` because it contains a colon? Is there only one value that needs to change or all values that contain colons should change to NaN?

Comment: Any value in Column 'Pet'.  There could be multiple in my dataset that have this attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [{'name': 'Pet'},{'name':'Dog-Ralph'},{'name':'Cat'},{'name':'2016-11-03 00:00:00'}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')

df
```

output:

```
    name
0   Pet
1   Dog-Ralph
2   Cat
3   2016-11-03 00:00:00
```

Find and replace using np.where as its faster : [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316)

```
df['name'] = np.where(df['name'].str.contains(":"), np.nan, df['name'])

df
```

output:

```
    name
0   Pet
1   Dog-Ralph
2   Cat
3   NaN
```

See np.where performance details : [Why is np.where faster than pd.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166348/why-is-np-where-faster-than-pd-apply)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df

#   Pet
#0  Dog-Ralph
#1  Cat
#2  2016-11-03 00:00:00

import numpy as np
df[df["Pet"].notnull() & df['Pet'].str.contains(":")] = np.nan
# replace any non-nan string with `colon` with np.nan    

df
#   Pet
#0  Dog-Ralph
#1  Cat
#2  NaN
```

Or if you only need to replace the `Pet` column:

```
df.loc[df["Pet"].notnull() & df["Pet"].str.contains(":"), "Pet"] = np.nan
```

Comment: I get the following error below when I run this: ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: Check the updated version, it's likely that you have some missing values in the column already, use `notnull()` to convert them to `False`.

Comment: Interesting, it worked for me for the dummy example, Perhaps, your data contains some special cases I can't think of.