# python pandas row wise substitution by condition in an elegant way

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem:

Given a dataframe, say for example,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,0,0,1],'col2':['B','B','A','A'],'col3':[1,2,3,4]})
```

In some other tool I can easily create a new column based on a condition, say

Create new column 'col3' with 'col2' if df['col1'] == '0' & ~df['col2'].isnull() else 'col1'

This other tool works it out pretty fast. I did not find a corresponding expression in python so far.

1.) I tried np.where which iterates through rows but does not allow dynamic values in the result corresponding to the exact row

2.) I've tried .apply(lambda ... ) which appears to be quiet slow.

I would be happy if you could find an elegant way to fix this problem. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 0 & (~df['col2'].isnull()), df['col2'], df['col1'] )
```

np.where is faster than pd.apply: [Why is np.where faster than pd.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166348/why-is-np-where-faster-than-pd-apply)

Answer (score 2):

I think need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `notnull` instead inverted `isnull` (thanks @jpp):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,0,0,1],'col2':['B','B','A','A'],'col3':[1,2,3,4]})

df['col3'] = np.where((df['col1'] == 0) & (df['col2'].notnull()), df['col2'], df['col1'])
print (df)
   col1 col2 col3
0     1    B    1
1     0    B    B
2     0    A    A
3     1    A    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.loc`:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1']
df.loc[(df['col1'] == 0 )& (~df['col2'].isnull()), 'col3'] = df['col2']
```