# Replace values in DataFrame column when they start with string using lambda

Tags: pandas, lambda, replace, apply, startswith

I have a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = {'Value': ['Test', 'XXX123', 'XXX456', 'Test']}
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

I want to replace the values starting with XXX with np.nan using lambda.

I have tried many things with replace, apply and map and the best I have been able to do is False, True, True, False.

The below works, but I would like to know a better way to do it and I think the apply, replace and a lambda is probably a better way to do it.

```
df.Value.loc[df.Value.str.startswith('XXX', na=False)] = np.nan
```

Comment: does your dataframe has just the 1 column? and apply isnt a preffered way bdw

Comment: dataframe has many columns

Comment: and each column has values starting with `XXX` which you want to replace with `np.nan` or is it just 1 column?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method

```
In [80]: x = {'Value': ['Test', 'XXX123', 'XXX456', 'Test']}
In [81]: df = pd.DataFrame(x)
In [82]: df.Value.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x.startswith('XXX') else x)
Out[82]:
0    Test
1     NaN
2     NaN
3    Test
Name: Value, dtype: object
```

Performance Comparision of apply, where, loc
[image]

Comment: Excellent. This answer helps me understand lambda better for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 5):

`np.where()` performs way better here:

```
df.Value=np.where(df.Value.str.startswith('XXX'),np.nan,df.Value)
```

Performance vs apply on larger dfs:

[image]

Comment: I like the np.where option you presented. How does the apply lambda test against it?

Comment: @McRae check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166348/why-is-np-where-faster-than-pd-apply)

Answer (score 1):

Use of `.loc` is not necessary. Write just:

```
df.Value[df.Value.str.startswith('XXX')] = np.nan
```

Lambda function could be necessary if you wanted to compute some
expression to be substituted. In this case just `np.nan` is enough.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It looks like I kind of fell on the right path anyway??

Comment: I thouhgt actually about applying a lambda function, which returns some value to be substituted. In this case the value to substitute is just *np.nan*, so there is no need to apply any lambda function.