# Use if condition in Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, formula

I have one dataframe, I'm trying to perform if function on the data, say if column A is 'ON' then Column E should be `Col C + Col D` otherwise Column E is `MAX(col B, col C)-col C + col D)`.

df1:

```
T_ID   A     B    C     D
1      ON   100   90    0
2      OFF  150   120  -20
3      OFF  200   150   0
4      ON   400   320   0
5      ON   100    60  -10
6      ON   250   200   0
```

Resulting Data frame

```
T_ID   A     B    C     D    E
1      ON   100   90    0     90
2      OFF  150   120  -20    10
3      OFF  200   150   0     50
4      ON   400   320   0    320
5      ON   100    60  -10    50
6      ON   250   200   0    200
```

I am using the following code, any suggestion how can I do it in a better way?

```
condition = df1['A'].eq('ON')

df1['E'] = np.where(condition, df1['C'] + df1['D'], max(df1['B'],df1['C'])-df1['C']+df1['D'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `np.where` here is good approach. For me working [`numpy.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html), `max` raise `error`:

```
condition = df1['A'].eq('ON')

df1['E'] = np.where(condition, 
                    df1['C'] + df1['D'], 
                    np.maximum(df1['B'],df1['C'])-df1['C']+df1['D'])
print (df1)
   T_ID    A    B    C   D    E
0     1   ON  100   90   0   90
1     2  OFF  150  120 -20   10
2     3  OFF  200  150   0   50
3     4   ON  400  320   0  320
4     5   ON  100   60 -10   50
5     6   ON  250  200   0  200
```

---

```
df1['E'] = np.where(condition, 
                    df1['C'] + df1['D'], 
                    max(df1['B'],df1['C'])-df1['C']+df1['D'])
print (df1)
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Here `apply` is worse solution, because loops under the hood, so slow:

```
#6k rows -> for sample data np.where is 265 times faster like apply
df1 = pd.concat([df1] * 1000, ignore_index=True)
print (df1)


In [73]: %%timeit
    ...: condition = df1['A'].eq('ON')
    ...: 
    ...: df1['E1'] = np.where(condition, 
    ...:                     df1['C'] + df1['D'], 
    ...:                     np.maximum(df1['B'],df1['C'])-df1['C']+df1['D'])
    ...:                     
1.91 ms ± 11.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [74]: %%timeit
    ...: df1['E2'] = df1.apply(createE, axis=1)
    ...: 
507 ms ± 11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `apply` function will be better solution. 
The code may like this:

```py
def createE(row):
   if row.A == 'ON':
      return row.C + row.D
   else:
      return max(row.B, row.C) - row.C + row.D
df1['E'] = df1.apply(createE)
```

See more about `apply` at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-the-existing-columns/

Comment: Yeah, I just google it, `np.where` is much more faster then `apply`. Here is the explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166348/why-is-np-where-faster-than-pd-apply

Comment: hmmm, can you explain why do you think `apply function will be better solution.` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i tried using the code but getting the following error, can you please see
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'A'