# iterating over each row in pandas to evaluate condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import numpy as np
import math

data = web.DataReader('goog', 'yahoo')
df['lifetime'] = data['High'].asfreq('D').rolling(window=999999, min_periods=1).max() #To check if it is a lifetime high
```

How can i compare it so that i get a boolean (in 1 and 0 preferably) if `df['High']` is close to its `df['lifetime']` for each row in pandas:

```
data['isclose'] = math.isclose(data['High'], data['lifetime'], rel_tol = 0.003)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.where()`

```
import numpy as np
import math

data['isclose'] = np.where(math.isclose(data['High'], data['lifetime'], rel_tol = 0.003), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `pandas`' [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function:

```py
import math

from pandas_datareader import data as web

data = web.DataReader("goog", "yahoo")

data["lifetime"] = data["High"].asfreq("D").rolling(window=999999, min_periods=1).max()

data["isclose"] = data.apply(
    lambda row: 1 if math.isclose(row["High"], row["lifetime"], rel_tol=0.003) else 0,
    axis=1,
)

print(data)
```

---

**However**, [yudhiesh's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69579495/42659) using [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is faster.
See also: [Why is np.where faster than pd.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166348/why-is-np-where-faster-than-pd-apply)