# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math

I have the following code which tests if a stock makes new lifetime high. Bool output should be generated with numpy comparison.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import numpy as np
import math

data = web.DataReader('goog', 'yahoo')
data['lifetime'] = data['High'].asfreq('D').rolling(window=999999, min_periods=1).max() #To check if it is a lifetime high
data['lifetime'] = data['lifetime'].astype(float)
data['isclose'] = np.where(math.isclose(data['High'], data['lifetime'], rel_tol = 0.003), 1, 0)
```

This solution which was offered here [iterating over each row in pandas to evaluate condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69579474/iterating-over-each-row-in-pandas-to-evaluate-condition?noredirect=1#comment122985914_69579474), should work but i am getting this error.

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

I did some looking and it seems that `math` function is expecting a single value and not an array. How can i verify that it is the case? [TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988348/typeerror-cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for working with arrays, here columns:

```
data['isclose'] = np.where(np.isclose(data['High'], data['lifetime'], rel_tol = 0.003), 1, 0)
```