# Matplotlib / Tkinter plot error with dataframe "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, typeerror

When using matplotlib ax.plot for a df column, I get this TypeError about converting series to float.

I have tried many options of forcing the column values to all convert to float before plotting, checking if there are any errors or missing values in the column (none).

This data is from an IoT device with timestamped data records - what is odd is before a certain date the plots work fine, after that date they don't. I know the IoT manufacturer made some updates for us to the device on that date, so it must be related to that, but i can't see any difference in how the data is formatted, and can't get any errors to show etc..

Could it be related to the devices reset meaning the timestamps for all my datapoints (they come from separate devices) are now all exactly in sync and so there are many duplicate timestamp entries in the dataset?

Any ideas on how to investigate the differences in the data returned, or other ways to check for errors that would give the below response, very welcome!

I have seen answers like this but this is code buried in matplotlib / tkinter (?) so not sure this will help:
[TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583661/typeerror-cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-float-in-pandas)

This is the terminal response when running it in debug on VS Code:

```
DatePicker(value=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0), description='Start Date:', step=1) TimePicker(value=datetime.time(0, 0), description='Start Time:', step=60.0)
<IPython.core.display.Markdown object>
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
<IPython.core.display.Markdown object>
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 861, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 274, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 10, in draw
    super().draw()
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 388, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 95, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 3154, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3070, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1979, in draw
    if not self.get_visible() or not self._check_xy(renderer):
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1574, in _check_xy
    xy_pixel = self._get_position_xy(renderer)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1565, in _get_position_xy
    return self._get_xy(renderer, self.xy, self.xycoords)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1463, in _get_xy
    y = float(self.convert_yunits(y))
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 230, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 861, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 274, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 10, in draw
    super().draw()
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 388, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 95, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 3154, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3070, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1979, in draw
    if not self.get_visible() or not self._check_xy(renderer):
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1574, in _check_xy
    xy_pixel = self._get_position_xy(renderer)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1565, in _get_position_xy
    return self._get_xy(renderer, self.xy, self.xycoords)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1463, in _get_xy
    y = float(self.convert_yunits(y))
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\repos\repo\venv-chart-py-api\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 230, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

This is the dataframe column, a snippet of its response:
`total_traffic_df[tr_fld_occupants]`
gives:

```
...
2023-12-12 23:59:00    22.0
2023-12-12 23:59:00    22.0
Name: Occupants, Length: 14400, dtype: float64
```