# Match words from one table to another table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, substring, text-mining

I am doing text mining, on table the below dataset

```
import pandas as pd

data_set = {
    'client_id': [
        100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108],
    'Category': [
        'house_Status','house_Status','house_Status','house_Status',
        'house_Status','house_Status','house_Status','house_Status','house_Status'],
    'description': [
        'i am homeless',
        'i am struggling to find home i am homeless',
        'i have home',
        'i am homeless and living in basement',
        'i have in public housing as rental are hard to find',
        'i sleep in garage',
        'I and my family are  homeless',
        'we live in public housing',
        'i am happy']}

data_set = pd.DataFrame(data_set)
data_set
```

I have another table where i have words to search

```
word_search={
    'Category' : ['house_Status','house_Status'],
    'Word_to_search':['homeless','public housing']}

word_search = pd.DataFrame(word_search)
word_search
```

Based on the category i have to find which description has that word

The code i am using is very basic i am joining the 2 datasets on category and creating a simple filter which is

```
test = pd.merge(
    data_set, word_search, left_on='Category', right_on='Category', how='inner')
```

ON this i am searching for substrings

```
test['status'] = test.apply(lambda x: x.Word_to_search in x.description, axis=1)
test
```

and taking only true values,

The problem with my solution is it is slow , i have many categories and many words to search over a dataset that is very huge, if there is a better way to solve this please let me know

In python or sql

Answer (score 0):

you can simply try using `np.where` conditions and flag the ids where the category and the keyword matches:

```
data_set['status'] = np.where(
    (data_set['Category'].str.contains(
        "|".join(set(word_search['Category'])), regex=True)) &
    (data_set['description'].str.contains(
        "|".join(set(word_search['Word_to_search'])), regex=True))
        ,1,0)

data_set



   client_id      Category                                        description  status
0        100  house_Status                                      i am homeless    True
1        101  house_Status         i am struggling to find home i am homeless    True
2        102  house_Status                                       i have  home   False
3        103  house_Status               i am homeless and living in basement    True
4        104  house_Status  i have in public housing as rental are hard to...    True
5        105  house_Status                                  i sleep in garage   False
6        106  house_Status                      I and my family are  homeless    True
7        107  house_Status                          we live in public housing    True
8        108  house_Status                                         i am happy   False
```

for just getting True values, just subset data like:

```
data_set = data_set[data_set['status'] == 'True']
```

let me know if this matches with your output. Usually np.where is faster than apply functions (refer to [Why is np.where faster than pd.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166348/why-is-np-where-faster-than-pd-apply) for timing related info)

Comment: Please upvote my answer if that helps you in any way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use the `loc` method (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). With your example that would give :

```
mask_category = data_set.Category.isin(word_search.Category.values) 
mask_description = pd.Series([False]*len(data_set),index=mask_category.index)
for s in word_search.Word_to_search:
    mask_description = mask_description | data_set.description.str.contains(s)

data_set.loc[mask_category & mask_description , :]
```

Explanation:
This method should be perform quicker than the lambda function

`data_set.loc[mask_category & mask_description , :]` will filter all rows where both `mask_category` and `mask_description` are `True` (`&` is the logical AND while `|` is the logical OR).  This check is done by index. `mask_category` and `mask_description` are simply pandas Series and their index corresponds to the index of `data_set`. So with the `loc` method we pass for each row a `True` or `False`

`data_set.Category.isin(word_search.Category)` will return a pandas series with the same index as `data_set` and a value giving us a `True` if the value in the column `Category` of `data_set` is an item of `word_search.Category` ie `'house_Status'` or `'house_Status'` given the two values are identical. You could speedup the process by calling `unique` to remove doublons: `data_set.Category.isin(word_search.Category.unique())`

The next blocks produces the series to filter on the description. `mask_description` will be `True` if the corresponding (correspondance by index) row of `data_set` contains one of the words contained in the column `Word_to_search` of the `word_search dataframe`.

```
mask_description = pd.Series([False]*len(data_set), index=mask_category.index)
for s in word_search.Word_to_search:
    mask_description = mask_description | data_set.description.str.contains(s)
```

You could shorten this using list comprehension but I think the above is more readable.

Do you get better results with this ?