# List comprehension to create a Pandas dataframe column based on values of 4 other other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'company_1': ['McDonalds', 'Mercedes', 'Apple'],
    'company_2': ['Wendys', 'BWM', 'Microsoft'],
    'company_1_price' : [3, 1, 4],
    'company_2_price' : [2, 8, 3]
})
```

I'd like to add a column to this `df` named `more_expensive`, which will be the company that is more expensive.

For example, the `df` would look as follows:

```
    company_1   company_2   company_1_price   company_2_price   more_expensive
0   McDonalds   Wendys      2                 3                 Wendys
1   Mercedes    BWM         7                 4                 Mercedes
2   Apple       Microsoft   9                 3                 Apple
```

How would I use list comprehension to add this column?

Thank you.

Comment: why list comprehension? You can use: `df['more_expensive'] = np.where(df['company_1_price'] > df['company_2_price'], df['company_1'], df['company_2'])`.

Comment: Yes, `np.where` does this job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can also use apply

```
df['company'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['company_1'] if row['company_1_price'] > row['company_2_price'] else row['company_2'], axis=1)
```

axis = 1 means rows
and what about we compare the running time for this case compare to the

```
df['company'] = np.where(df['company_1_price'] > df['company_2_price'], df['company_1'], df['company_2'])
```

Time for np.where method:

```
start = time.time()    
df['company'] = np.where(df['company_1_price'] > df['company_2_price'], df['company_1'], df['company_2'])
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
print(df)
```

**result is 0.0013189315795898438s**

Time for df.apply method:

```
start = time.time()
df['company'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['company_1'] if row['company_1_price'] > row['company_2_price'] else row['company_2'], axis=1)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
print(df)
```

**result is 0.0021517276763916016**

Why is this?
refer to this link [Why is np.where faster than pd.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166348/why-is-np-where-faster-than-pd-apply)

To summarize, main reason because of the loop in df.apply and try to use `vectorization`